# Uso de Semana y Mes como filtro

Tags: soporte

he intentado usar los tabs de Semana y Mes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como usuario y programador yo esperaría que al darle click a una de estas dos opciones me cargue ***TODOS*** los POST correspondiente a la semana actual y al mes Actual; con la opción de paginación habilitada, como esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero este no es el caso solo me cargan unos cuantos ... me he percatado que se usa un criterio:
**Preguntas con más vistas, respuestas y votos esta semana/mes** pero desconozco a partir de que métrica comienzan a salir aquí los POST.

***¿Dónde puedo encontrar informacion sobre la métrica aplicada a este filtro?***

Comment: [Aqui](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/4789/346768) se explica el criterio para que una pregunta aparezca en preguntas principales. Y yo entiendo que aparecen todas las que en el ultimo mes/semana entran en dicha categoría

Comment: @Pikoh gracias, segun lo que veo y leo no todas las preguntas cumplen con el criterio.

Comment: Como usuario y programador también puedo entender que el filtro semana / mes (o cualquiera de los que aparece en esa vista) sólo me trae resultados parciales, es decir, las TOP N clasificadas según ese filtro, y no **todas** las preguntas. Estás mostrando el filtro de la página de *Inicio*, si te fijas el título es *Preguntas Principales*, en cambio si haces clic en *Preguntas* del menú de la izquierda, el título de dicha vista es *Todas las preguntas*. En esa página de **todas** las preguntas si es necesario el uso de un paginado.

Comment: @MauricioContreras no has entendido ...  no estoy discutiendo sobre el tema de si son todas o si son parciales, mi post no es un post de discusión ... es sobre soporte ... lograste leer la pregunta, es lo único que espero que respondan y ya lo hizo Pikoh.